# Calculating the contribution percentage in a Google document?

Tags: google-drive, statistics

I am looking for a program, Web service or browser extension that could calculate the authorship percentage in a Google document. Free and compatible with Windows 7 and Google Chrome is possible.

---

My use case: I have a Google document where 4 people contributed. I would like to get a sense of how much each of them contributed, like [TortoiseSVN does for SVN repositories](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23406956/395857)?:

[image]